# Jquery slide up again

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a div wich slides up and down after i click on another div.

this is my jquery code:

```
 $('#SchimbareEmail').click(function () {
        $('.SchimbareParola').animate({top: '+=234px'}, 200);
    });
```

When i click **#SchimbareEmail** div **.SchimbareParola** goes down by 234 px but when i click again it goes down again and i want it to get up by 234px after the second click.Does anynone have any idea how i can manage this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, using **[conditional(ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**

```js
$('#SchimbareEmail').click(function() {
  $('.SchimbareParola').animate({
    top: (this.toggle ? '-=234px' : '+=234px')
  }, 200);
  this.toggle = !this.toggle;
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<button id="SchimbareEmail">Click!!</button>
<div style="position:relative;width:100px;height:10px;background:black;" class="SchimbareParola"></div>
```

Comment: @Urarii : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Add a class that states whether it is down or up.

```
var div = $('.SchimbareParola');

if(div.hasClass('down')){
    div.animate({top: '-=234px'}, 200).addClass('up').removeClass('down');
} else {
    div.animate({top: '+=234px'}, 200).addClass('down').removeClass('up');
}
```

Then, in the function, check which class it is to determine whether to increase or decrease the top property.

Using the classes in this manner may help you style it, and manager other visual elements as well depending on it's position.